Have netdata running but cant reach it from remote
I have started netdata on Ubuntu 20.04 for the first time. I changed the bind address to the one of the server. I checked the status and it say active. When I look in the config file its almost empty. The last line is the one for the bind address
What am I doing wrong. I try 1.1.1.1:19999 but cant find
